# how to set shape editabe from kml

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, polygon

Im loading a kml file in my maps api and im using this code af a click event.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
    setSelection(kmlEvent.featureData.name);                            
    //alert(kmlEvent.featureData.name);
    //showInContentWindow(text);
});
```

Thats calls a function

```
function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
}
```

No i have 2 problems with it, the KML file gives me 2 polygons with each a different name.
`Tester` and `jahoor`. But when i click on `jahoor` it always gives me the polygon `Tester`.
Why cant i select them different from each other?

The second problem is, i cant set the polygon from the kml editable again.
It gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object Tester has no method 'setEditable'`

Does somebody know what im doing wrong? Can find it on stack or in the documents from the google api

Piece of the kml file:

```
<Placemark id="Tester">
    <styleUrl>#transYellowPolyActive</styleUrl>
    <name>Tester</name>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
            <tessellate>0</tessellate>
            <coordinates>                                           6.30889892578125,53.28820543193896 6.29791259765625,53.28410053532493 6.233367919921875,53.21096737507053 6.5093994140625,53.19698389904798 6.50390625,53.27096221595853
            </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="jahoor">
    <styleUrl>#transYellowPolyActive</styleUrl>
        <name>jahoor</name>
            <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                <tessellate>0</tessellate>
                <coordinates>                                           6.168479919433594,53.30318495818702 6.143760681152344,53.29579845109269 6.138267517089844,53.27281003615208 6.195259094238281,53.2707568976735 6.2010955810546875,53.29867113343524
                </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
```

Comment: Error `Object Tester has no method 'setEditable'` could be because you call Tester constructor without using `new`. The other sounds like closure problem but without code is hard to say.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Please

Comment: `new`: your object Tester is obviously defined. If not you'd get error about undefined object. It's seems like it's not properly initialized. The reason could be for example instead of calling `new name.pkg.Tester()` you just called `name.pgk.Tester()`. This is just a  guess.

Comment: It gives me anew error: `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: Could you show relevant code? It's hard to help without it.

Comment: Can you be more precicly with what you call relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Polygons from KmlLayer can't be made editable, they are rendered as tiles, not native polygons.  If you use a third party KML parser like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/), to render them as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 Polygons, you can make them editable.  But beware, that will be less efficient than tile based rendering, particularly for complex polygons or lots of polygons.

If I modify your kml to make it valid:

```
<kml>
<Document>
<Placemark id="Tester">
    <styleUrl>#transYellowPolyActive</styleUrl>
    <name>Tester</name>
    <Polygon>
        <outerBoundaryIs>
            <LinearRing>
            <tessellate>0</tessellate>
            <coordinates>                                           6.30889892578125,53.28820543193896 6.29791259765625,53.28410053532493 6.233367919921875,53.21096737507053 6.5093994140625,53.19698389904798 6.50390625,53.27096221595853
            </coordinates>
            </LinearRing>
        </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
</Placemark>
<Placemark id="jahoor">
    <styleUrl>#transYellowPolyActive</styleUrl>
        <name>jahoor</name>
            <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                <tessellate>0</tessellate>
                <coordinates>                                           6.168479919433594,53.30318495818702 6.143760681152344,53.29579845109269 6.138267517089844,53.27281003615208 6.195259094238281,53.2707568976735 6.2010955810546875,53.29867113343524
                </coordinates>
                    </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

And paste it into [this page](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)

Then click "parse KML to map", it gives me two editable polygons.

Or just click "parse KML to map" on [this map](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html?kml=%3Ckml%3E%0A%3CDocument%3E%0A%3CPlacemark%20id%3D%22Tester%22%3E%0A%3CstyleUrl%3E%23transYellowPolyActive%3C%2FstyleUrl%3E%0A%3Cname%3ETester%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%3CPolygon%3E%3CouterBoundaryIs%3E%3CLinearRing%3E%3Ctessellate%3E0%3C%2Ftessellate%3E%0A%3Ccoordinates%3E6.30889892578125%2C53.28820543193896%206.29791259765625%2C53.28410053532493%206.233367919921875%2C53.21096737507053%206.5093994140625%2C53.19698389904798%206.50390625%2C53.27096221595853%0A%3C%2Fcoordinates%3E%3C%2FLinearRing%3E%3C%2FouterBoundaryIs%3E%3C%2FPolygon%3E%0A%3C%2FPlacemark%3E%0A%3CPlacemark%20id%3D%22jahoor%22%3E%0A%3CstyleUrl%3E%23transYellowPolyActive%3C%2FstyleUrl%3E%0A%3Cname%3Ejahoor%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%3CPolygon%3E%3CouterBoundaryIs%3E%3CLinearRing%3E%3Ctessellate%3E0%3C%2Ftessellate%3E%0A%3Ccoordinates%3E6.168479919433594%2C53.30318495818702%206.143760681152344%2C53.29579845109269%206.138267517089844%2C53.27281003615208%206.195259094238281%2C53.2707568976735%206.2010955810546875%2C53.29867113343524%0A%3C%2Fcoordinates%3E%3C%2FLinearRing%3E%3C%2FouterBoundaryIs%3E%3C%2FPolygon%3E%0A%3C%2FPlacemark%3E%0A%3C%2FDocument%3E%0A%3C%2Fkml%3E)

Comment: hi, my kml is valid, what you see in my question is a part of it.. So if i want to change my kml polygons i need to make a new system that works with geoxml ?

Comment: That is one way to accomplish your goal, if your KML is not too complex. It is possible that you could use FusionTables/FusionTablesLayer also (use FusionTablesLayer to display the non-editable polygons, something like geoxml3 to parse KML to native editable polygons for those you need to modify).

Comment: The way im doing it, a user can draw a polygon, fill in some fields from te pop up en safe it in the database. Then the api opens the kml generetad file with the data from the database and he returns te polygons on the map. But i need it to be editable when a user clicks on the polygon.

Comment: Then I would suggest you get the data for the polygon from the database and use it to generate an editable polygon when your user wants to edit it.  The native Google Maps Javascript API v3 polygon will appear above the KmlLayer.